# Why is the homogeneity problem actually a problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

I don't mean to be flippant but I have never understood why the homogeneity in the universe needs.explaining. I have searched other questions on stack exchange and they don't really address the question. I am going to ask.

Say a bunch of identical particles are created contained in a void of absolutely nothing. They are endowed with a set of quantum laws and the quantum mechanics is deterministic. Initially, they are in thermodynamic equilibrium. They begin to expand so fast that they break into regions that are causally disconnected. Then each of these regions is identical, has the same set of laws and zero external influence by definition. Surely they are each essentially an initial. value problem with the same start conditions. Mathematically they should all evolve the same, shouldn't they? Even if QM were not a deterministic theory, these regions are identical, isolated and have the same laws. How could they evolve differently? And, unless they either have different sets of laws, different starting conditions, or some differing external influence from another source, how could they ever be different?

Comment: Isn't the situation you are describing (a dense region expanding into a void) nonhomogeneous?

Comment: Only at the boundary.  Away from the boundary I would have thought it will require some sort of "release."wave to carry information about the bounday to points in the interior. Until this arrives the interior point will not be aware of the boundary. .I presume that for any given region of space that there develops a spherical horizon, beyond which, no matter can have an influence. But without something to break the symmetry, I don't know why we should expect these rainsto evolve.differently. What am I missing?

Comment: So you're asking why we need inflation to get homogeneity, if you can just assume everything starts in contact in thermal equilibrium?

Comment: Well, that is the whole point of inflation. If you _don't_ have inflation, then there _never_ is a time when different ends of the observable universe are in contact. Inflation adds a period early in the universe where there is contact. Your argument is correct, but it shows why inflation is necessary, not why it isn't.

Comment: The early universe was *not* in thermal equilibrium. If it had been, then by the second law of thermodynamics it would have stayed in equilibrium, and we wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Rory Cornish The universe doesn't have a boundary, according to current models. Even if the density is large enough that the universe is finite, it is still considered to be unbounded.

Comment: Hello knzhou. I don't think the ends of the universe would ever be "in contact" as all particles will be a finite distance apart, so that the boundary containing all the particles should be a finite distance apart; so I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean causally connected-i.e having a relative speed low enough to permit information transfer from on end to the other?

Comment: Knzhou:  Suppose NO inflation was to occur. Then you would still have a bunch of identical particles and identical laws. Any local region of space should evolve identically shouldn't it, even if "adjacent" regions cannot communicate with each other".  Do you know what precisely is the reason that this is not the case, and what precisely does inflation do to solve this? I am not saying there is no need for inflation, but have I only ever heard woolly sounding explanations and never a well articulated reason based on solid physics.

Comment: Ben. Fair point. But our current universe is very uniform and that is what I was trying to capture with a simplified example.Simply replace the notion that the particles start in thermodynamic equilibrium to the notion that they are initially very uniform. I mean "uniform" in the same context as we mean today when we say that our universe is very uniform. Then the exact same argument applies. All regions start the same (i.e. uniformity) and have the same laws. Why would they ever evolve differently? Why is inflation necessary.

Comment: Hi D. Hasley. I wasn't suggesting that there is a boundary necessarily, just addressing the case for the world view that there may be one. By finite, or bounded, I would mean in the sense of a metric space, where you can choose a finite size open ball containing the whole set (the set being all the points on the Universe thought of as a manifold). It could theoretically be like a closed surface, a bit like a soap bubble (i.e. constant positive curvature) in which case it would be bounded and yet have no boundary. Isn't our observable region of the universe measured to be very flat?

Comment: @Rory Cornish You need to put the "@" symbol in front of the name of the person you are addressing (and spell the name correctly). Otherwise your comment will often be missed.

Comment: @D.Halsey. Thanks for that tip. Re  my question, I suspect the answer may be local stability in the sense of how we might expect a small perturbation to evolve. I wonder if the evolutionary laws are unstable such that a small perturbation would be expected to rapidly grow. A bit like the way a crack forms or a river forms. Maybe adding inflation changes the evolution to a stable one where small perturbations will tend to  decay. It is the only logical explanation I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, the quantum fluctuations that occurred in the early universe grew via a process called Jeans Instability and formed the cosmic structure that we observe.

As you know there are four components in the universe. These are dark energy ($\varepsilon_{\Lambda}$), dark matter ($\varepsilon_{DM}$), baryonic matter ($\varepsilon_{b}$) and radiation ($\varepsilon_{r}$).

First of all, $\Lambda$ does not fluctuate since the energy density is constant. ($\varepsilon_{\Lambda} = \varepsilon_{\Lambda,0}$)

During the RD(radiation dominated) universe CDM and BM fluctuations cannot grow   inside the horizon (due to Meszaros effect and baryon-photon decoupling). At the MD(matter-dominated) universe CDM starts to fluctuate however BM cannot, since its still coupled to the radiation. So CDM fluctuations start to grow. When the BM decouples from radiation (occurred around $z\approx 1000$), it falls into the potential created by the CDM particles.

Since the density fluctuations of these components evolve differently during the RD and MD universe, we cannot expect perfect homogeneity and isotropy. Also, currently, the universe is not perfectly homogeneous or isotropic. We are just making an approximation or assumption.

Since this is a complex topic, I cannot explain the details of it here. However, If you want to learn about how these fluctuations evolve I recommend you to read these books and articles.

1 - Cosmology: The Origin and Evolution of Cosmic Structure 1st Edition
by Prof Peter Coles, Francesco Lucchin

2 - Christos G Tsagas. Cosmological perturbations (https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0201405)

3 - David Tong. Structure formation, 2019. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/cosmo.html

4 - Malcolm S. Longair. Galaxy Formation (Astronomy and Astrophysics Library)